# Azure view public dns name in dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

In my virtual machine dashboard, I added the `public DNS name` column.

Is it supposed to be detected automatically or should I set it somewhere? If so, where?

[image: Public DNS Name]

Comment: well, do those machines have a public ip attached to their network cards?

Comment: Sure! And a `ANAME` attached to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Azure Portal, `Public DNS Name` means `Fully Qualified Domain Name`. The portal does not create a fully qualified domain name, or FQDN, by default, you can add one once the VM is created.

When you create a FQDN on Azure Portal, you could see it on `PUBLIC DNS NAME` column.

[image]
[image]

More information about how to create FQDN on Azure Portal please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-portal-create-fqdn).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping I could anotate my VM with it's usage domain name but apparently I can't.